# Disable cross button from the window.open popup

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee

Disable title bar or cross button  from the window.open

```
ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty docProd.url}" >

<script>window.open('flows/Ad/test.xhtml','center', "_blank", "titlebar=0");

</script><p:commandButton value="close"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

i have tried doing many things,,but this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. wrong syntax - this will open a window `window.open('flows/Ad/test.xhtml',"_blank")` - possibly with parameters `window.open('flows/Ad/test.xhtml', "_blank","top=200,left=300")`
2. not possible to remove the [X] in any current browser unless you use divs

Take a look at [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)